# Create new rows in SAS equal to the value of variable

Tags: sas, datastep

I am trying to insert new rows for each id, the number of rows should be equal to the value of a certain variable.

For example, say I have the variables ID and X1 which look like this:

```
ID      X1
A       3
B       1
C       5
```

Then I want the table to be produced as this:

```
ID
A
A
A
B
C
C
C
C
C
```

So there are 3 rows for A, 1 for B, and 5 for C. Thanks.

Comment: Why? What did you try?  How close did it come?

Comment: The X1 variable represents how many occurrences are remaining for each ID. To perform a forecast for each upcoming period I need to have each ID repeat for as many remaining periods that are left. I've tried some macro work but I am very limited in skill

Comment: This does not require a macro, it's a basic DO loop with an OUTPUT statement.

Comment: First one is a freebie, but please post an attempt next time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DO loop with an explicit OUTPUT statement to duplicate the records X1 times.

```
data want;
     set have;
     do i=1 to x1;
        output;
     end;
   run;
```